# Sending ints over sockets in swift

Tags: python, ios, sockets, swift

I'm writing an application in swift with a server side that has been writing in python.
I'm struggling with sending the data the right way.
Lets say the the server side is designed to receive a int - which means will be represented something like '\x00\x00\x00\x05'.

Now lets say I have a int variable x with the value of 5 in my swift code.
How can I serialize it or mangle it in any way to to convert it into that string and send it via the socket?

Comment: If the server is designed to receive an int, it could quite possibly expect `5` as `\x05\x00\x00\x00`, depending on the processor, OS, and server code.

Comment: Correct, my problem is how do i get to a point in swift where im sending this data.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a C or ObjC bridge and use C code. Does Swift even have direct access to sockets yet?

Comment: I'm currently sending data using OutputStream.Write method and im able to send a simple string but i cant make that string represent the int in the right way as - '\x00\x00\x00\x05'

Comment: Take some time and learn about bytes, ints, data, endian-ness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the number form little endian to big endian (also know as Network Standard Order).

```
var number : UInt32 = 5
var numberBE = number.bigEndian

var data = NSMutableData()
data.appendBytes(&number, length: 4)
println(data) // <05000000>

var dataBE = NSMutableData()
dataBE.appendBytes(&numberBE, length: 4)
println(dataBE) // <00000005>
```

Comment: This is the result i'm getting now.
The problem with that is if im sending it on the socket the '<' and '>' are sending too, and \x is not added when i see it in python.

Comment: The '<' and '>' are just an artifact of the description method. What you want to send are the bytes. The data has exactly 4 bytes. To get a pointer to the bytes: `data.bytes`.